# What happened to Justice, Nelson Mandela's cousin (or stepbrother)?

Tags: 20th-century, south-africa

Reading *Long Walk to Freedom*, Nelson Mandela ran away from his guardian, Jogintaba the regent of Transkei, with the regent's son who was called Justice. Then Justice simply drops out of the story. What happened to Justice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Nelson Mandela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson_Mandela) and Justice Mtirara ran away to [Johannesburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannesburg), where a former member of Chief Jongintaba's court worked as an overseer at Crown Mines. He found them both jobs: Mtirara as a clerk, and Mandela a security guard. Their brief careers ended however when Jongintaba tracked them down and ordered them back.

Justice returned home and succeeded his father. [He passed away in 1974](http://www.news24.com/Archives/City-Press/Madiba-saved-my-marriage-20150429). Mandela meanwhile stayed in Johannesburg and got into politics.

> He sent men out to track down the runaways. When he learned that they had gone to Johannesburg and were working at Crown Mines, he telegraphed to the overseer and told him to dismiss Mtirara and Mandela and send them home. Their careers at Crown were over.
>
> Mtirara returned home, but Mandela managed to persuade Jongintaba that he should remain in Johannesburg, where he could study law.
>
> **<sub>- Stefoff, Rebecca. *Nelson Mandela: A Voice Set Free*. Fawcett, 1990.</sub>**